# How to publishHTML reports always even on fail

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have the below declarative pipeline in my Jenkinsfile for the publishHTML:

```
stage('Compile-ExecuteTests-GenerateReport'){
  agent {node 'Automation'}       
    steps{
       echo "Running the smoke tests"
       sh 'mvn clean verify -Denv="test" -Dtags="smokeTest" serenity:aggregate'

       publishHTML target: [
        allowMissing: false,
        alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
        keepAll: true,
        reportName : 'Serenity Report',
        reportDir:   'target/site/serenity',
        reportFiles: 'index.html'
      ]
    }       
  }
```

this publishes the report when the tests pass but when the tests fails report does not get published. In the declarative pipeline is there a way to publish report on fail or pass?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move publish report into `post` as following:

```
stage('..'){
  agent {node '...'} 

  steps{
    ...
  }
  post {
    always {
      publishHTML ...
    }
  }      
}
```

Comment: Thanks yong. Will try the solution.

Comment: That worked, I was doing a post always after all the stages instead of at the stage('Compile-ExecuteTests-GenerateReport'), thanks yong.

Comment: @arthi if you don't mind, please upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: @hakamairi when I try to vote I get the a warning saying votes cast by less than 15 reputations is recorded and my vote is not recorded. How to accept the answer?